# MySQL error 1064 on website database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am a little embarrassed asking this question but I seem to be stumped.
I am using MySQL 5.7 and am trying to upload to my online server which has MySQL 5.6.  phpMyAdmin was used create the database. I get the same error when I try to restore the database in my local phpMyAdmin (part of my WAMP server).
I have also studied the My SQL reference documentation as well as several internet searches.  Here is the error:
SQL query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `heyx1_assets`;
CREATE TABLE `heyx1_assets` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key',
`parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT
) ;
```

MySQL said:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that.
>
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near ')' at line 4

Any help will be appreciated. My client is becoming very impatient.

Comment: Why is the comment that it's a primary key but it's not *actually* set `PRIMARY KEY`?

Answer (score 1):

You have a `COMMENT`, but no comment.  You need a string after `COMMENT`:

```
CREATE TABLE `heyx1_assets` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Primary Key',
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Comment goes here'
---------------------------------------------------^
) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Which phpMyAdmin versions are you using on each server? This seems like it may have been a bug with an older version of phpMyAdmin (which had trouble exporting in a similar way to what you're describing); I suggest you upgrade to the latest (which is currently 4.6.5.2).

You can also edit the SQL file to manually fix the COMMENT as shown by Gordon Linoff.